# Why I can't disable spring boot auto generated password and user?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I m starting a new spring boot project, desiring to disable the auto configured user in Spring Security, I tried a lot of configuration but none works, I don't know what I m missing ? !!!

**First here is my project dependencies**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bridjit.esport</groupId>
    <artifactId>esport_1.0</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>esport 1.0</name>
    <description>hand made spring backend project for esport project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-classpath</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-classpath</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outputFile>classpath.txt</outputFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

as you see I m using **spring boot 2.1.5** with **web flux, security, mongo, actuator**

to disable  the auto user configuration I tried to implement my own `UserDetailService` withe security as shown below

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public SecurityConfigurer(EsportUserDetailService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
public class EsportUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> userFindByUsername = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        User user = new User();
        if (userFindByUsername.isPresent()) user = userFindByUsername.get();
        return new EsportPrincipal(user);
    }


}
```

```
@Configuration
public class BeansConfig{


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoding(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public EsportUserDetailService getEsportUsersDetailSericeImplementation(){
        return new EsportUserDetailService();
    }

}
```

when I run using the maven spring-boot plugin my app starts fine it connects to my mongodb docker container, but I m still getting the password and the user autoconfigured, what I m missing in my configuration ?
[image: As you see there is a user password]

Comment: Can you confirm that EsportUserDetailService is being loaded (maybe add some debug msgs). You might need to specify ComponentScan in your main class

Comment: I added a log in the service constructor then  I added a simple log in the bean registration: result Working fine :/

Comment: By bean registration, you mean the call to auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder) ? and userDetailsService is not null even in constructor there is no @Autowired?

Comment: yes because here I m using contructor autowiring, this is a best practice to avoid being bound by the autowired if some day I want to reuse my code in another java project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using WebFlux rather than Spring MVC , you have to use [WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-webflux) Security .

To disable that default user and password configured by SpringBoot , you have to implement `ReactiveUserDetailsService` instead.